Django ViewFlow - Add dropdown selector to BPMN process step
Have a basic ViewFlow BPMN Process Flow set up.
How can i add a dropdown selector to a step in the BPMN process with for instance a dropdown list of selections e.g. Users or Companies that needs to be selected as part of the step?
the jsonstore proxy class does not have a dropdown option. Can i use the Forms and embed in the step somehow?
thanks

Viewflow is the thin workflow layer on top of standard django Model/Forms/View/Templates framework
You can use standard Django forms as usual with Viewflow
class CompanySelectionForm(forms.Form): 
   company = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Company.objects.all(), 
    label="Select Company")

The selected company can be saved in a view to task.seed, task.artifact, process.seed, or process.artifact fields, depending on what it means for your flow. You can also save it as a primary key in a jsonstore, or by inheriting the process model without the abstract=True flag to store the company in a separate table.
If the selected company is not workflow-related data but part of a model created during the workflow, the process.artifact should point to that model, and the model should have a foreign key field to the company.
You can read more about data management in the Viewflow docs - https://docs.viewflow.io/workflow/data_flow.html
